# Is there syntax error in my code?

Tags: php, syntax, switch-statement

Is there a syntax error in my code?  Everything seems to work ok..This is a question asked on a self study test, and I don't want to get caught in a 'stump the chump', trick question..

```
$i = fgets(STDIN);

switch ($i) {
      case 'a':
      case 'i':
      case 'e':
      case 'u':
      case 'o':
         echo("vowel\n");
      default:
         echo("non vowel\n");
 }
```

Comment: To check for syntax errors, execute `php -l filename.php` from the command line

Comment: But there is a logical error, the fact that you don't `break` after `echo("vowel\n");` means that the code will also execute the default block as well

Comment: also see what prints when you enter a vowel, might not be what you expect.

Comment: It's not necessary to break out of any case of a switch statement in PHP, but if you want only one case to be executed, you have do break out of it (even out of the default case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it does work, it's not quite "right". You forgot to `break` out of the vowel case.

Personally, however, I wouldn't use a `switch` for this. I would probably do:

```
$vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
if( in_array(strtolower($i),$vowels)) {
    echo "vowel\n";
}
else {
    echo "consonant\n"; // the proper word for "non-vowel" :p
}
```

This is because you have a two-case statement: either it is, or else it isn't. `switch` is suboptimal for this kind of thing, and - as shown by the error in your code - more prone to errors ;)

Comment: Thanks @Niet the Dark Absol!  That's the Silver Bullet answer!